# How to change woocommerce stock status using xml feed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an xml file uploaded in my domain containing products availabilities. How can I update stock status with this? I am thinking something like the following but I confused about how I can call and use it

```
function wc_update_product_stock_status() { 
    global $xml; 
    foreach($xml as $x) {
        $sku = $x->sku;     
        $availability = $x->availability;
        switch($availability) {
            case 1:
                $status='instock';
            break;
            case 0:
                $status='outofstock';
            break;
        }
        // get the product ID from the SKU
        $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku'AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ));
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        if ( $product ) {
            $product->set_stock_status( $status );
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to add something to make it better?

thank you

Comment: you can use WordPress cron schedule to run this function every-time your downloaded the XML file, or you can use Linux Cron to run the functions

Comment: I get Call to undefined function wc_update_product_stock_status() with my code and I dont know why

Comment: how are you calling your function ?

Comment: wc_update_product_stock_status(); Do I need a hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't modify function which woocommerce is declared before or write use same function which is declared before, so if you want to write custom function you can do the following:

> Notice i have modified the function name

```
function update_product_stock_status() {
    global $xml;
    foreach ( $xml as $x ) {
        $sku          = $x->sku;
        $availability = $x->availability;
        switch ( $availability ) {
            case 1:
                $status = 'instock';
                break;
            case 0:
                $status = 'outofstock';
                break;
        }
        // get the product ID from the SKU
        $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );
        $product    = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        if ( $product ) {
            $product->set_stock_status( $status );
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}



add_action( 'init', 'update_product_stock_status' );
```

or if you want you can use `wc_get_product_id_by_sku` within your custom function  as follow:

```
function update_product_stock_status() {
    global $xml;
    foreach ( $xml as $x ) {
        $sku          = $x->sku;
        $availability = $x->availability;
        switch ( $availability ) {
            case 1:
                $status = 'instock';
                break;
            case 0:
                $status = 'outofstock';
                break;
        }
        // get the product ID from the SKU
        $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $sku );

        if ( $product_id ) {
            wc_update_product_stock_status( $product_id, $status );
        }
    }
}



add_action( 'init', 'update_product_stock_status' );
```

I called this function using `init` hook which Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.

but that's of course not the best way you need to hook your function using WordPress cron job to be run every-time you updated the XML file.  or better by using the linux crontab.

so for example to run your function using Wordpress Cron you can do it by adding the following:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_stock_update' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_stock_update' );
}

add_action( 'my_stock_update', 'update_product_stock_status' );
```

with this code above your function will run every hour, and  of course you can modify that.

for more details about WordPress Cron check this link below:

[Reference 1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron)

[Reference 2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event)